# In android native developments are fragments necessary if I am only using jetpack compose for the UI?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-jetpack-compose, android-xml

I am working on learning native android development with kotlin and jetpack compose. I am currently looking into fragments and data binding. I have seen a lot of references to fragments as a concept and from what I understand they are used to setup/implement reusable UI components in an android app. My question is are fragments still important to use if I am using jetpack compose for UI instead of XML views? A lot of the resources I am finding on fragments are only discussing it in the context of using them for XML UI. If anyone has any resources that discuss using fragements with jetpack compose that would be useful as well. Thanks!

Comment: Fragments are required when only some part of your app is in Jetpack Compose. This is usually in migration process. You use ComposeView inside your fragment while writing your Compose code inside. Or you might consider using fragments you are really unsatisfied with Jetpack Compose navigation and would like to continue using Android Navigation components.

Comment: If you do not have legacy code, then fragments are not needed to develop with jetpack compose

Comment: You need fragments as its lifecycle aware. Android already have custom view but you need lifecycle to efficiently manage view state.